# Is it possible to authenticate a Rest API with OpenId Connect and pass credentials from the client

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have a .Net Core REST API which is secured with OpenId-Connect authentication. We need to call it via a Console Application and would like to pass the username and password from the outside, so that we don't have to go through a browser login page.

The programmatic API request:

```
var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
authRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
```

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Update: Here's an example to do it with ADAL: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore/tree/master/TodoListClient. If you don't use multi factor authentication a simple http request will do as @NanYu suggested.

Comment: Does your API endpoint accept "username and password" or "authorization" token?

Comment: The API redirects to Azure AD which asks for a username and password and then returns and Authorization Token.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc directly use http post , ADAL is not needed .

Comment: I have seen this done on Linux. 
Might want to look at: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/16/oauth-2-command-line

Comment: Thanks for your response @NanYu. A direct http post would work without multi factor authentication. In our scenario, one point I missed, we use multi-factor authentication, which means we can't authenticate without a prompt.

Comment: @user3167162 ,the resource owner flow can't work together with  multi factor authentication , you should pick other authentication flow if you want the 2FA feature

Answer (score 0):

Which implementation of openid connect are you using? I have done this in IdentityServer 4. All you have to do is add a ressource owner client in the Identity Sever configuration.

```
 new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ro.client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "yourScope"}
```

See the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, we plan on supporting both Azure AD and IdentityServer.